# Ubuntu 10.04 not seeing SCSI scanner (Scanpartner 15c)

Tags: drivers, 10.04, scanner

I'm unable to see my old-school SCSI scanner in Ubuntu 10.04.

Here's what dmesg, lsscsi, and lsmod show:

```
root:~# dmesg | grep Adaptec
[   18.586163] scsi5 : Adaptec AIC7XXX EISA/VLB/PCI SCSI HBA DRIVER, Rev 7.0
[   18.586164]         <Adaptec 2902/04/10/15/20C/30C SCSI adapter>
```

This suggests to me that the SCSI card is being seen, and there is a valid driver.

lsmod output:
`scsi_transport_spi     26284  1 aic7xxx`

lsscsi ouput:

```
root:~# lsscsi -H
[0]    ata_piix      
[1]    ata_piix      
[2]    ata_piix      
[3]    ata_piix      
[4]    usb-storage   
[5]    aic7xxx       
[6]    usb-storage
```

My question is: What other troubleshooting steps should I take?

Answer (score 1):

Recent releases of the sane (Scanner Access Now Easy) packages apparently removed support for the Fujitsu scanpartner.

So while the sane-fujitsu system of backends no longer

Apparently the sane-sp15c backends do.

Will test and report results here.

Details: http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-sp15c.5.html

See also:

- http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-fujitsu.5.html